360 degree angle measurement using MPU6050
This is the first time I am working with PMU6050 sensor to detect the tilt angle of the PCB. I have read as much as possible and could get it working up to a certain level. Now the code measures the Roll and Pitch as 45 degree, when the sensor is perpendicular on X or Y axis. So basically it measure -90 - 0 - +90, I was expecting measuring -180 - 0 - +180...
here is the output when the ROLL is at near 45, then sensor is perpendicular on Y axis.

Here is the code, I have come across with so far...
MPU6050 setup
MPU6050_Write(MPUAddress, PWR_MGMT_1_REG, 0, 20);
delayMs(10);

//GYRO FULL SCALE setting
/*
* FS_SEL  Full Scale Range
* 0   +-250 degree/s
* 1     +-500 degree/s
* 2     +-1000 degree/s
* 3     +-2000 degree/s 
*/
MPU6050_Write(MPUAddress, GYRO_CONFIG_REG, 0, 10);
delayMs(10);

//ACCEL FULL SCALE setting
/*
* FS_SEL  Full Scale Range
* 0   +-2g
* 1     +-4g
* 2     +-8g
* 3     +-16g   
*/
MPU6050_Write(MPUAddress, ACCEL_CONFIG_REG, 0, 10);
delayMs(10);

/*Sample Rate = Gyroscope Output Rate / (1 + SMPRT_DIV) */
MPU6050_Write(MPUAddress, SMPLRT_DIV_REG, 39, 10); // Sample Rate = 200Hz
delayMs(10);

/*DLPF is set to 0*/
MPU6050_Write(MPUAddress, MPU6050_CONFIG_REG, 0b00000100, 10);
delayMs(10);

Reading the values
MPU6050->AcclX = ((twoComplementsToSignedInt(dataAccel[0] << 8 | dataAccel[1], 16) - MPU6050->XBias) / 16384.f) * GRAVITY_MS2;
        MPU6050->AcclY = ((twoComplementsToSignedInt(dataAccel[2] << 8 | dataAccel[3], 16) - MPU6050->YBias) / 16384.f) * GRAVITY_MS2;
        MPU6050->AcclZ = ((twoComplementsToSignedInt(dataAccel[4] << 8 | dataAccel[5], 16) - MPU6050->ZBias) / 16384.f) * GRAVITY_MS2 ;

Angle->AcclPitch  = (int32_t)(atan2(MPU6050->AcclX, (sqrt(pow(MPU6050->AcclY,2) + pow(MPU6050->AcclZ,2)))) * RADIAN_TO_DEGREE);
        Angle->AcclRoll = (int32_t)(atan2(MPU6050->AcclY, (sqrt(pow(MPU6050->AcclX,2) + pow(MPU6050->AcclZ,2)))) * RADIAN_TO_DEGREE);
        Angle->AcclYaw = (int32_t)(atan2((sqrt(pow(MPU6050->AcclX, 2) + pow(MPU6050->AcclY, 2))), MPU6050->AcclZ) * RADIAN_TO_DEGREE);


